# Is there an easy fix to my code to get the mysql Update statement working in csharp?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Good evening.

I cant get the Mysql Update Statement working.
Maybe i am missing something.

The same mysqlconnection worked flawlessly to Select and Insert Data.
FYI those sections(Select and Insert) are commented out.

I get following 4 error messages:

- MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
- MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed.
- IOException
- SocketException

Full exception:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Fatal error encountered during command execution.
  Source=MySql.Data
  StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at sqltest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\chaos\Dropbox\Visual Studio\Mysqltest\sqltest\sqltest\Program.cs:line 35

Inner Exception 1:
MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.

Inner Exception 2:
MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed.

Inner Exception 3:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Inner Exception 4:
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Is this the actual table name discordbot.tb_lurk ? Or you meant to write discordbot.dbo.tb_lurk?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c40077afd9653047196e16cb2ac7429f

Comment: Discordbot is the schema and "tb_lurk" is the table.
https://gyazo.com/c40077afd9653047196e16cb2ac7429f

If i try the SQL-Query in workbench it works fine but not in the c# application.
I figured that i dont have to write "discordbot" since im not using root user.
The c# application gets acces through the user "discordbot"
But that doesn't fix the Problem (fatal Errors).
https://gyazo.com/b317746408a6d9ec6526e2af2d7af730

Comment: can you post your connection string?

Comment: i added both classes to the main question (connection string)

Comment: The error message is complaining about the reading from the result set, but `ExecuteNonQuery()` explicitly **ignores** any result set. Are you sure this code is where the exception is thrown, and it's not a later statement?

Comment: I just pasted the code above into a fresh project with mysql nuget and added connection classes DBUtils and DBMySQLUtils. I adjusted namespaces.
And if i execute i get the same errors.
https://gyazo.com/acadab1b2b2496f61966fa3f98cf7846

Comment: Can you past full details of Exception you get please?

Comment: @ MKR: I did add the full details of Exception on the end of the post up ahead.

Comment: IS your MySql server running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys... I thank everyone single one of you who tried to help me.

I found the error. The Mysql Server was running on Version 5.7.17.
I did not update the server but installed the new version of Mysql Benchmark instead on the Windowsserver 2012. I can not open the new Benchmark but it fixed the communication Problem.

I have no clue whatsoever why certain statements did work (Insert, Select) but UPDATE did not.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions from me:

1. Have you tried creating the command like this? var cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQL_update, conn); after opening the connection, then doing the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ?
2. Have you tried having the connection string looking like this instead?
   "SERVER=" + server + ";DATABASE=" + database + ";UID=" + username + ";PASSWORD=" + password;

... where "server" is ip/servername + port, like "myserver:3306". If server is local server, I THINK server can be "localhost" without port if the port is the standard port.

Comment: @ Mats Magnem
https://gyazo.com/0ff6b2c3c74dc2edfcacd23ff896a2ca

Comment: Ok, too bad. Then I believe it is about the availability of your server. Like port blocked I'm firewall, wrong ip/network or something like that. The suggested connection string also didn't work?

Comment: @MatsMagnem If server was behind firewall or not accessible then `conn.Open();` would fail. Perhaps we need to see details of actual exception.

Comment: It can not be a connection/port error, because it's running on a dedicated machine in a datacenter. In the following screenshot you will see, that i can use select without any problem but for some reason update wont work at all.
https://gyazo.com/7b01145ef757012d30b68f205c5e23b4

Comment: @ MKR: I did add the full details of Exception on the end of the post up ahead.

Comment: @mkr hmmmm, yes that is indeed true... Then I need to see the exception details.